# Powershell - officially-blessed verb for "Toggle"

Tags: powershell

I have a couple powershell functions that do things like check if a program is open, then close it. Or if the program is closed, the function opens it. These functions are appropriately named `Toggle-Something`. I use them in shortcuts on my windows taskbar for starting/stopping a group of applications at once (like all my chat/email programs).

However, now I am getting warnings about unapproved verbs. I don't see anything on the list of approved verbs that seems appropriate. Is there an approved verb synonym for `Toggle`?

Comment: You can get a list of the verbs by typing `verb` or `Get-Verb`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Switch`, which is an approved verb -

Switch (sw) Specifies an action that alternates between two resources, such as to change between two locations, responsibilities, or states.